# laravel 5.5. how to response a redirect from a action, not the route action

Tags: laravel, response

I want to check the auth before run the action. if the user deny, I will response the 403 status.

I use the method function  in the __construct to check .

the code is following.

The User Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{


    if (!app()->runningInConsole()) {
        $beforeMethod = \Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod()."before";
        if (method_exists($this, $beforeMethod)) {
            return $this->$beforeMethod();
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Edit interface.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return Content
 */
public function edit($id)
{


    return "success";
}

/**
 * Check user Auth
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function editBefore()
{
    $id = \request()->route('user');
    if (Gate::denies('edit', User::find($id))) {

        return redirect("login");

    }
}
```

the above code, don't return to the login.

what code should I use to achieve my purpose？ Thanks!

Comment: use `this->middleware('auth')`

Comment: Look at the laravel documentation of middleware and apply that.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close to what I would do. I would use [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#gates).

You can add these to the routes or route groups so that you can check the policy before it hits the controller method whatsoever.

Create a new policy class that looks something like:

```
class UserPolicy 
{
    public function canEdit(User $user) // this user is the logged in user
    {
        // Here you return true or false depending on whether they can edit or not.

        return $user->isAllowedToEdit();
    }
}
```

Then you make sure the policy is added to `AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $gate->define('user.edit', UserPolicy::class.'@canEdit');
    // Additional policies
}
```

Then make sure to add `can` to your `$routeMiddleware` in the `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other middleware
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

Finally, you can add it to your route making sure that you use the same name you defined in the `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
Route::get('/user/edit')
    ->uses('UserController@edit')
    ->middleware('can:user.edit');
```

I personally like doing it this way because it cleans up the controllers and lets the policies do all the work "behind the scenes". Even better, you can then use that same `users.edit` policy for multiple routes.

Comment: yeh! But I want to define a before action for the real action,  i can define the before action freedom, when the before action return false,  the real action will not execute.